# Окончание числительных во всплывающей подсказке кол-ва ответов

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Очередная ошибка с окончанием числительных, в этот раз заметно на вопросах, имеющих один ответ:

[image: 1 ответов]

В данном случае текст хинта должен совпадать с текстом в блоке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В transifex присутствуют несколько вариантов с разными названиями переменных:

1. > [$numAnswers$ answers](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267745?key=6f41a0f26c0de90b3c3e3a611c6261bf)
2. > [$AnswerCount$ answers](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267745?key=caecc1a440e01e57f75e723115830044)
3. > [$num$ answers](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267745?key=6dbf23e49d77444924503ee0513484af)
4. > [$__count$ Answers](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267745?key=61f4ac871cdbcdd29ff7c27fa4518087)
5. > [$TotalWithCommas$ Answers](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267745?key=6437f43f414f53c702c252d3f806c68b)

Варианты 1 и 5 были с ошибками. Поправил их, требуется утверждение редактором.